# How to make bit column like in SQL Server using Laravel Database Migration

Tags: sql-server, laravel, database-migration, laravel-migrations, dbmigrate

So I'm creating a new table, replicating an existing table, and one of them has a column of type bit, like this:
[image: screenshot]

I already understand the concept of migration and have made it often, but to create this column of bit type via migration, what type of column should I use from what [Laravel provides here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#available-column-types)?

I've been looking for references, but haven't found an answer yet.

Thank you, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a column with type of `bit` by using the `binary` in the migration. Here is an example to it

`$table->binary('column_name');`

Comment: Yes this solved the problem, it creates Varbit column, but the `->default(0)` makes the code error, so i remove it

Comment: Accepted the edited one